# Why does this C code snippet not result in a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, dereference

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned int ptr1 = *((unsigned int *)(argv[1]));
    printf("ptr1 = 0x%x\n", ptr1);
    exit(0);
}
```

This is a code snippet from a video tutorial. I am not sure whether I understand why the code doesn't result in a segmentation fault when run.

`(unsigned int *)(argv[1])` This looks like the first argument passed to the program gets casted to an unsigned int. So, if the argument was 'AAAA' then '0x41414141' is now a pointer to some place in memory.

And then when we do this - `*((unsigned int *)(argv[1]))`, aren't we deferencing the value pointed to by address `0x41414141`? From what I know, this address is probably not accessible by the process. So how come no segmentation fault occurs? The output of the program is -

`ptr1 = 0x41414141`

I have compiled this program on Linux with gcc.

Comment: `argv[1]` holds a pointer to `char` data, you cast that pointer (not what it points to) to treat it as a pointer to `unsigned int` data, then dereference *that*. You're not dereferencing `0x41414141`. You're dereferencing `argv[0]`, but doing it with `unsigned int *` colored glasses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: This answer explains how the code works in this particular case, for more complete answer please refer to @Lundin post.

---

`(unsigned int *)(argv[1])` converts a `char*` to `unsigned int*`.

`*((unsigned int *)(argv[1]))` dereferences converted `char*` to `unsigned int*`.

Suppose, `argv[1]` points to `AAAA` string. It stored in the memory as `41 41 41 41` (in hex). Then you're interpreting this as `unsigned int` and it results in `ptr1 = 0x41414141`.

Take look at the following diagram: the left viewer interprets the memory as `char*` and the right viewer interprets it as `unsigned int*` (do not care care about little-endian / big-endian differences):

[image]

So, there is no reason for segfault

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a good answer, as you almost don't mention any of all the poorly-defined behavior in the code. Readers of this answer might assume that the OP's code is perfectly fine code and that the mentioned tutorial isn't  crap.

Comment: `So, there is no reason for segfault` it's incorrect, there is. You can cast anything to `char*` but doing in the reverse way invokes undefined behavior. It's not guaranteed to work because `argv[1]` isn't necessarily properly aligned. It works here simply because x86 supports unaligned access but most other architectures prohibited it

Comment: @Lundin, Agreed. Waiting for the OP to uncheck the accept button so I can remove the answer.

Answer (score 5):

This code is dangerous and bad. Step-by-step explanation of what the code does and why that is bad:

- `argv` is an array of pointers to character (`char*[]`). Or if you will, a pointer (`char**`) to the first item in such an array of pointers to character.
- `argv[0]` points at the name of the executable and `argv[1]` is a pointer to the first argument passed.
- `(unsigned int *)(argv[1])` casts the pointer to the first argument, a `char*`, to a pointer to int, `unsigned int*`. This is by no means guaranteed to be a safe conversion. There are two major bugs here:

  - If this new integer address is misaligned, accessing it will invoke undefined behavior, possibly a program crash.
  - The conversion is a violation of the strict aliasing rule, which (simply put) states that the compiler may assume that the contents pointed at by a `char*` is never accessed through some other random pointer type. So the compiler may assume that the memory pointed at by `argv[i]` is never used by your program. Any strange optimization might occur as you invoke undefined behavior.
- Given that a particular compiler specifies deterministic behavior for the pointer conversion as a non-standard extension, then it would attempt to access the pointed-at string as if it was an integer. If the string was for example `"ABCD"`, then the resulting integer (assuming 32 bit) would either be `0x41424344` or `0x44434241`. Which applies depends on CPU endianess. Such code would be non-portable.

However, just accessing the memory pointed at by the `argv` array will of course not cause any implications. If you couldn't read this memory, then it would be impossible for you to use the argv parameters. Exactly how they are stored is OS-dependent, but it has to be inside address space that your process is allowed to access.

So the program will certainly not crash or seg fault because of that, as long as you keep access within allocated memory. If the string `argv[1]` had just been 1 character long, you would likely have gotten a seg fault.

Comment: Advice: please stop watching that Youtube tutorial immediately. Leave a comment and say that it is a bad tutorial. Feel free to post a link to this post to warn others from watching it.

Comment: Actually the author acknowledges that the code is nasty, but the context is different. Here is a [link](https://youtu.be/jWI_XjHb12g?t=189) to the video.

Comment: @user1720897 Well... durr. The code in that video is not the same as in your question. He is storing the result in an `unsigned int*` whereas you store it in `unsigned int`. Quite a different program (but just as bad). The video seems to be about hacking data into various static memory locations and with the usual garage-hacker mentality: "lets hope this works" or "wow it worked this time".

Comment: Yes. The code is different. I was playing around with the code trying to explain the code to myself and I stumbled on something that I didn't understand.

Comment: @user1720897 Storing the result in a pointer makes a bit more sense though, it means that he is essentially trying to pass an address to his own program through command line parameters, but in an obfuscated and bad way.